# Running multiple integration tests against a database - with no conflict

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have a bunch of different Entity Framework integration tests. Each of course starts with EnsureDeleted()/EnsureCreated(). And here's the problem.

If they all use the same database, then tests will fail when xUnit runs multiple tests at the same time and they lock over the database.

If they all use a different database, then I'm going to end up with 15 - 30 test databases on my system (granted, not the end of the world).

Is there a solution to this that avoids this issue? The only thing I've come up with is:

1. Tell xUnit to run all integration tests sequentially - which slows things down a lot.
2. Give each test its own database name and call EnsureDeleted() at the end of each test.
3. Another approach???

Any suggestions to this issue? I'm thinking the EnsureDeleted() at the end of each test - are there any problems with that approach?

Comment: Look at this [Testing against your production database system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-with-the-database) and this [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0). / In general, integration tests are often really slow, so they are performed quite rarely.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Wow - your two links are one of the most helpful short replies I have ever received here. Thank you - this helps for more than just this question. Have a wonderful day. And if you post your comment as a question - I'll happily select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from @AlexanderPetrov with the two excellent links, I set it up that each unit test has a different DB name for its test.

And I do the following (works great):

```
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();

// all the tests

context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

You can put it in a try/finally with the final EnsureDeleted() in the finally. I did not do that because often, when the test fails, I find the DB contents useful for figuring out why it failed.